# C++: Using sizeof() division to find the size of a vector

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to get the size of a vector as a number so that I can use it as a **constexpr**.

The `vector.size()` returns a size type that is not a constant expression. Therefore, I thought to use `sizeof(vector) / sizeof(vector[0])` to get an integer value which I can manually use in a constexpr initialization.

```
const vector<int> int_vec = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
cout << sizeof(int_vec) / sizeof(int_vec[0]) << endl;
```

My CLion compiler always prints 6. I do not understand why. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks for the response.
I learned that I can use `sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0])` to find the length of an array. So how would this not work for a vector?

Comment: Simple `sizeof` does not return the size of a vector. If `vector.size()` does not work for you then nothing will.

Comment: Incidentally `vector.size()` is a constexpr from C++20. So maybe you can upgrade your C++ version.

Comment: `sizeof(vector)` is the size of the container object, not the data stored inside it. It will never change no matter how much data is stored in the vector.

Comment: @john It won't work here though without some tricks that are probably too convoluted, because you can't put `constexpr` on the vector itself.

Comment: Have you tried using `std:array`? That one has a constexpr size.

Comment: @Goswin von Brederlow Thank you! I do know about arrays. This question was asked for one of my exercise question on C++ Primer, which force me to make an array from a vector. Thus, I need to find a constexpr for size of the vector to initialize my array. (Array only take constexpr for sized initialization. This question seems badly designed so I hard coded the size and went on.

Comment: @Pictsit I had the same problem making a `constexpr` array of primes smaller than `N`. The way I solved it I made a `constexpr` function returning how many primes will be generated and used that instead of `vector.size()`. It's kind of annoying that not everything that is constant evaluated can be used as a constexpr.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason why `vector.size()` isn't `constexpr` is that `std::vector` grows as you add data to it; it has a variable size that is not known at compile time. (That's what `constexpr` means, that the value of the expression is known at compile time.)

What `sizeof (vector)` gets you is the size of the in-memory representation of the `vector` class, which has nothing to do with how many elements are stored in it. This obviously can't be correct because `vector` is a class name, not a variable name, so it can't possibly return the size of any one specific vector.

Using `sizeof int_vec`, which by the way does not require parentheses, as `sizeof` is an operator and not a function, is a little more rational, since at least you're asking about the size of some specific vector and not all vectors in general. But again the problem is that you're going to get the size of the in-memory representation, which has to be fixed. After all, you can instantiate one on the stack, and so it has to be of some fixed size so that C++ knows how much space to allocate for it. It can't just expand in place as you add elements to it, because it would overwrite other data on the stack. It has to have some internal pointer to dynamically-allocated memory for storing the elements. When you do `sizeof int_vec` you're getting the space needed for this pointer and other internal data, not the space needed for the elements themselves.

If you want an array-like container that has a size that's fixed at compile time, try `std::array`.

Comment: Thank you! That made things clear. I would love to give you an upvote but I am a new user.